Is the OECD BCI Dataset fit for use with Linear Regression?
I am wondering if the OECD Business Confidence Index can be utilised by a linear regression model for time-series data.
I have had a look at the ‘basis of prep, for the data and I am rather confused (link below).
The data seems to be smoothed, normalised and then ‘amplitude adjusted’ and I must admit I am having a hard time understanding whether these steps make this data more suitable or less suitable for a linear regression model.
I was wondering if someone could please have a look at the basis of prep and see if anything sets alarm bells off?
Please note, I am required to use a linear regression model for this so other, perhaps more appropriate models are out of the question.
Thanks very much!
https://www.oecd.org/sdd/leading-indicators/45430429.pdf
